# Magnet links do not display data in uTorrent

Tags: windows-7, bittorrent, utorrent

For some reason on certain websites when I press on magnet links it redirects me to 'Add new torrent' and its empty. Size: 0B and the list below it is empty too.

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Question was reopened and comments deleted, see [What to do about torrents?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1596/what-to-do-about-torrents) This one is deemed legal.

Comment: Magnet links from some websites(e.g. tpb) lack that info...
you will have to start the download for the info to be populated.
later, you can switch to files tab and skip/prioritize the files of your choice..

Answer (score 14):

Magnet links work by your machine retrieving the torrent information from other peers. This includes the torrent size and etc.

this means when you first download the magnet link file your machine won't know anything about the torrent. After a short while of running the torrent you should find utorrent populates the information. The amount of time taken depends on the number of available peers, etc.

Comment: I think you didn't understand me. when i press on the magnet icon on pirate bay it redirects me to utorrent and i got this: dl.dropbox.com/u/15358757/12.jpg

Comment: Your screenshot changes your question from "I'm having trouble using this application" to "I'm having trouble pirating this television show".

Comment: My thoughts entirely.

Comment: what can i say .. i live in a country which doesn't air this program on tv so i dont have any 'legal' way to watch it.

Comment: In short. Hit Ok, and things will go as per normal

Comment: @JourneymanGeek What if I want to chose only part of the files? I need to wait for it to load or what?

Comment: start download, let information be populated. then select files, i suppose

Comment: @RonKantor: That's how magnet links work, they only consist of a hash. All the rest still has to be obtained from the P2P network, you can select which files to download under the Files tab. The context menu is your best friend...

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason on certain websites when I press on magnet links it redirects me to 'Add new torrent' and its empty. Size: 0B and the list below it is empty too.
>
> Magnet links do not display data in uTorrent

No, and it wouldn’t because that’s normal for magnet links.

When you download a `.torrent` file, it is several kilobytes large and contains all the information necessary for using the torrent including the file and folder names, sizes, and hashes of all of the torrent’s files.

Magnet links are only a couple of dozen bytes and contain only the name and hash of the torrent itself (not its files). (I don’t see why the total size of the torrent couldn’t also be included for convenience, but it’s not.)

When you use a magnet link, it will be devoid of any content and you must start it to retrieve the information that `.torrent` files contain. You get this information from other peers and µTorrent notifies you in the log:

> [2012-07-23 00:56:51]  Finished receiving metadata for 'Really Cool Torrent'

(You will also know when it has retrieved the metadata because the torrent’s *Selected Size* column will change from `0 B` and the *Files* tab will become populated.

Similar to magnet links are [`ed2k` links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed2k_URI_scheme) for the eDonkey network. Unlike magnet links however, `ed2k` links, they [can contain all the information necessary](http://www.emule-project.net/home/perl/help.cgi?l=1&rm=show_topic&topic_id=422) including the files’ names, sizes, and hashes.